# Get DbSet name from class object type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to get the DbSet name from the class object type. This is the definition of the DbSet in the DbContext:

```
public DbSet<User.Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Now, from `typeof(Role)` I need the get the name of the DbSet "Roles".

There is any way to get this?

Comment: I've got a few questions: Are you using Entity Framework 6?, You need to find the `Property` called `Roles` in the DbContext or just the type of  `DbSet<User.Role>`?

Comment: Hi Andrés. Yes! I'm using EF6. I just need to get the name "Roles" in string it's okay. From typeof(Role)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
public static void Main()
{
    var roleType = typeof(User.Role);

    var context = new FakeDbContext();

    var propertyInfo = GetDbSetProperty(roleType, context);

    Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}

public static PropertyInfo GetDbSetProperty(Type typeOfEntity, FakeDbContext context)
{
    var genericDbSetType = typeof(DbSet<>);
    // typeof(DbSet<User.Role>);
    var entityDbSetType = genericDbSetType.MakeGenericType(typeOfEntity);

    // DbContext type
    var contextType = context.GetType();

    return contextType
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == entityDbSetType)
        .FirstOrDefault();      
}

public class FakeDbContext
{
    public DbSet<User.Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class DbSet<T>
{
}

public class User
{
    public class Role
    {
    }
}
```